# CSS table > td - force content to one line cross-browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

**This is working on Chrome/Edge:**

```html
<style>
  .o {
    width: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
</style>

<table style="width:100%; position: relative; border-collapse: collapse">
  <tr>
    <td class="o">text no wrap</td>
    <th>Head</th>
    <td class="o">text no wrap</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`white-space: nowrap;` ... stops wraping

`width: 1px;` ... auto expend content to minimum needed width

**This are the problems:**

- *internet explorer:* auto-expand width not working. (customers still use them, although i don't like ie)

So there is a wrap if width is set. Without width `td`s are to big (empty space) because of the missing minimize to content.

- *cross-browser:* if content is too big, without wrapping, it expands table-witdh over 100%. Better would be a "only wrap if really needed".

*side information: i cannot use a fixed layout, because content is filled from a database*

Comment: it seems to work fine the same way in all browser for me. ie is indicating : `width: 79.98px`when you inspect and check the calculated value. So auto expand works on ie 11

Comment: if i try it in ie 11, than "text no wrap" is wrapped at every space...

Comment: No we don't have the same html. Mine is correctly incremented, with `doctype`,  `html` > `head` > `style`, `body` > `table`. Dont expect IE to set element in good place, you should be the one setting them correctly as I made in my answer. your html is wrong the way you made it (delete this answer and edit your post with the image)

Comment: You are absolutely right. Inserting "<!doctype html>" made it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to respect HTML structure in IE. And not just set randomly your style and table.

And it seems to work fine the same way in all browser for me. ie is indicating : `width: 79.98px` when you inspect and check the calculated value. So auto expand works on ie 11

You might have more css or html but just as you gave. IE11 is making the job as per capture:

[image]